# Dynamically add or remove input fields as they're required

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, input

I have a set-up of multiple file inputs, which I've styled by hiding the inputs, creating my own in html/css and then controlling the original inputs through jQuery to get the functionality.

I want to be able to add another input and associated HTML if all the inputs are filled, like this:

- start with 1 input
- if this gets filled/ used, add another input
- repeat
- remove cleared inputs, only ever leaving 1 empty input for use.

I tried creating a js fiddle with my code, but it doesn't seem to work through it, so here's a link to the test on my site: [LINK](http://ry-design.co.uk/image-upload-test.php)

and the code, JS:

```
$('.file-browse').click(function(){
    var thisone = $(this).attr('id');
    $('input[name="input-'+ thisone+'"]').click();
});

$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(){
    var thetext = $(this).val();
    var thetextsplit = thetext.split('\\').pop();
    var thisone = $(this).attr('name').split('-').pop();
    if($('div[id^="info-file"]').text() == thetextsplit){
        alert('you have already selected this file');
        $(this).replaceWith( $(this).val('').clone( true ) );
    }
    else{
        $('#info-'+ thisone).text(thetextsplit);
        $('#clear-'+ thisone).fadeIn(100);
    }
});

$('.file-clear').click(function(){
    var thisone = $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop();
    $('input[name="input'+ thisone +'"]').replaceWith( $('input[name="input'+ thisone +'"]').val('').clone( true ) );
    $('#info-'+ thisone).text('');
    $(this).fadeOut(100);
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="file-container">
      <div class="file-info" id="info-file1"></div>
      <div class="file-browse" id="file1">Browse</div>
      <div class="file-clear" id="clear-file1">X</div>
    </div>

    <div class="file-container">
      <div class="file-info" id="info-file2"></div>
      <div class="file-browse" id="file2">Browse</div>
      <div class="file-clear" id="clear-file2">X</div>
    </div>


    <div class="file-container">
      <div class="file-info" id="info-file3"></div>
      <div class="file-browse" id="file3">Browse</div>
      <div class="file-clear" id="clear-file3">X</div>
    </div>

    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type='file' name="input-file1" class="file-input-hidden" />
      <input type='file' name="input-file2" class="file-input-hidden" />
      <input type='file' name="input-file3" class="file-input-hidden" />   
  <input type="submit" style="clear:both; float:left;"/>
    </form>
```

CSS:

```
.file-container{
clear:both;
float:left;
width:445px;
height:40px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.file-info{
float:left;
width:250px;
height:15px;
padding:5px;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #95d2d2;
margin:0 20px 0 0;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#373737;
overflow:hidden;
}

.file-browse{
float:left;
width:100px;
height:15px;
padding:3px 5px 8px 5px;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #95d2d2;
background-color:#02b3b3;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial, Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:normal;
text-align:center;  
cursor:pointer;
}

.file-input-hidden{
opacity:0;
visibility:hidden;
float:left;
}

.file-clear{
display:none;
float: left;
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
padding: 5px;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #CC0000;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 20px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Sorry about the lengthy post! I wasn't sure of the best way to show my work so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rpsep,

I think things would be simpler starting with a template :

```
<div id="input_template" style="display:none;">
    <div class="file-container">
        <div class="file-info"></div>
        <div class="file-browse">Browse</div>
        <div class="file-clear">X</div>
    </div>
    <input type='file' name="input-file[]" class="file-input-hidden" />
</div>
```

Notes:

- Only the outer container has an id; everything else has a class.
- Don't worry about the input element being in the same container as the everything else; after cloning it will be put in the proper place.

Then attach functionality to the template :

```
$("#input_template").find('.file-browse').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest(".file-container").data('hidden').click();
});

$("#input_template").find('.file-clear').on('click', function(){
    $container = $(this).closest(".file-container");
    $container.data('hidden').remove();
    $container.remove();
});

$('#input_template').find(".file-input-hidden").on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
    var $visible = $(this).data('visible');
    var $matches = $(".file-info").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === val;
    });
    if($matches.length > 0) {
        alert('You have already selected this file');
        var $clone = $this.val('').clone(true);
        $visible.data('hidden', $clone);
        $this.replaceWith( $clone );
    }
    else{
/*
        $visible.find(".file-info").text(val);
        $visible.find(".file-clear").fadeIn(100);
        makeInputSet();
*/
        var $fi = $visible.find(".file-info");
        if(!$fi.text()) 
            makeInputSet();
        $fi.text(val).end().find(".file-clear").fadeIn(100);
    }
});
```

*It would probably be better to delegate the event handling to containers, but this code was easier to write, based on the code in the question.*

Invoke the template with the following function, then create the first instance by calling it immediately:

```
function makeInputSet() {
    var $visible = $("#input_set").find(".file-container").clone(true, true).appendTo("#...");//appropriate selector required
    var $hidden = $("#input_set").find(".file-input-hidden").clone(true, true).appendTo("#...");//appropriate selector required
    $visible.data('hidden', $hidden);
    $hidden.data('visible', $visible);
}

makeInputSet();
```

Notes:

- `makeInputSet()` is then called from inside the 'change' handler whenever an existing input field (and its visible counterpart) gets populated.
- the two `.data()` calls ensure that the hidden element and the visible elements have the means of communicating with each other without having to string-handle ids or form rather inefficient closures.

*Everything is untested, therfore probably needs debugging*

Comment: this works very well! thank you. the only part which doesn't is where it checks to see if a file has already been selected:  if($visible.find(".file-info").text() == val) {
alert('You have already selected this file');
$(this).replaceWith( $(this).val('').clone(true) );
}  but reading it in my head it seems like it should? any ideas?

Comment: Ah yes, the test was incorrect. The new `val` needs to be tested against the text of *each* existing `.file-info` div. Your original approach, if it works, is probably the best but I've just edited my answer with something different; namely using `.map()` to loop through the existing `.file-info` divs looking for matches, then testing the length of the resulting jQuery obj.

Comment: Just got round to testing this, and it's `.filter()`, not `.map()`.

Comment: Just had yet another look and found another issue. As it stands, if an input is "re-Browsed", and a different file successfully selected, then a further new input will be made, even though a blank input already exists. I think your original code would have behaved the same way. This can be overcome by calling `makeInputSet()` only if the blank input is populated. See revised code above.